# Find sum of largest repeated number in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to find largest repeated number in an array and summation of it.

While going through here , I found the solution to find max number. But now I need to count how many max(largest) number is there and store number of maximum number and then summation.

*Example:- array- [5,5,7,9,9,9] . So max number is 9 and it is 3 times so , it will store in another array [9,9,9] and total = 27.*

I got this to find max number in an array:-

```
function evaluate() {
  const input = prompt("Please enter the array of integers in the form: 1,2,3,1")
    .split(',')
    .map(nums => nums.trim());

  function max(numArray) 
{
    var nums = numArray.slice();
    if (nums.length == 1) { return nums[0]; }
    if (parseInt(nums[0]) < parseInt(nums[1])) { nums.splice(0,1); }
    else { nums.splice(1,1); }    
    return max(nums);
}


  if (input == "" || input == null) {
            document.writeln("Sorry, there is nothing that can be calculated."); 
        } else {    

  document.writeln("The largest number is: ");
  document.writeln(max(input) + " with a starting input string of: " + input);
}
}
evaluate();
```

So I want my final output to be shown is `27` from the above example.

Comment: `it will store in another array ` Do you *need* another array, or do you really just want the `27`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance As of now `27` (final output) only.

Comment: Instead of using split+map+trim you could just use `match(/\d+/g)`. There is also no need for *parseInt* in `parseInt(nums[0]) < parseInt(nums[1])`, you can use just `nums[0] < nums[1]` as relational expressions using `<` coerce both operands to number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns an object with the specified outputs `{max: 9, items: [9,9,9], sum: 27}`.

```js
function maxElementSum(arr) {
    var max = Math.max(...arr)
    var count = arr.filter(el => el == max).length
    return {max: max, items: Array(count).fill(max), sum: max * count}
}

console.log(maxElementSum([5,5,7,9,9,9]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.max` to get the largest value and then use the `filter` & `reduce` to sum the value

```js
// find the largest number
var _gt = Math.max(...[5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9])
// then filter the array and get the largest values
// and use reduce to sum the numbers
var arr = [5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9].filter(function(item) {
  return _gt === item
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc += curr;
  return acc;

}, 0);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count the values, reduce the max count and return the multiplication of value and count.

```js
var array = [5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9],
    max = Object
        .entries(
            array.reduce((r, v) => (r[v] = (r[v] || 0) + 1, r), Object.create(null))
        )
        .reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b)
        .reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start with an array, then you only need *reduce* to both find the maximum value and to return the sum, e.g.

```js
var nums = [5,5,7,9,9,9],
    max  = -Infinity,
    result = nums.reduce((acc, num) => num > max? acc = max = num : num == max? acc += num : acc, 0);

console.log('Result: ' + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily just using one forEach loop in O(n) time,

```
var array = [5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9];
var max = array[0], total = 0;
array.forEach((a)=>{
  if(a==max){
    total+=max;
  }
  else if(a>max){
    max = total = a;
  }
});
console.log("total:"+total);
```